# Runtime DEV environment variable for React Js (web)

Tags: reactjs

Just like React Native,

When I am testing some web application in development mode I would like to prevent rendering few blocks.

Is there some runtime environment variable like **DEV** (boolean) in React Js for web?

I wonder if I may be able to do it by setting some cli param like `npm start --dev=true`?

Comment: react.js runs client-side, so it doesn't have automatic access to vars in your server or shell env. are you using webpack, @Magalhães Lage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your react project is a create-react-app project then there is a special built-in environment variable called *NODE_ENV*. You can read it from `process.env.NODE_ENV`. When you run `npm start`, it is always equal to *'development'*, when you `run npm test` it is always equal to *'test'*, and when you run `npm run build` to make a production bundle, it is always equal to *'production'*.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the env like so:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  console.log('dev');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 'npm start' you could pass environment variables. 
Put the following in your package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "ENV=PRODUCTION react-scripts start",
    "dev": "ENV=DEV react-scripts start"
  }
```

Then do 'npm start' for production and 'npm run dev' for dev setup.